# Python FTP object returns socket.error: [Errno 10060] behind HTTP Proxy?

Tags: python, ftp

```
from ftplib import FTP
import time

try:
    ftp = FTP('kcm.amazon-digital-ftp.com') # removed "sftp://" from url.
except IOError, e:
    time.sleep(120)
    ftp = FTP('kcm.amazon-digital-ftp.com')
```

This returns "socket.error: [Errno 10060]" I'm running this script from a VM, which has a proxy on it. I'm able to connect to this ftp site using Filezilla on the same VM without changing Filezilla's proxy settings.

In that case, I don't understand how FileZilla is dealing with that proxy in the background and how to mimic that in my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I was trying to use FTPlib which doesn't support SFTP.

This worked for me in what I was trying to achieve:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635163/3219210