# Connecting to SFTP client using proxy command in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, sftp, ssh-tunnel

I need to connect to SFTP server using proxy command.

I know how to connect to SFTP server directly:
[paramiko's sshclient with sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3635131/850848)

I can open an SSH connection via proxy command using this code:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
target_host = 'sftp.XXXXX.co'
target_port = 22
proxy = paramiko.proxy.ProxyCommand('/usr/bin/nc --proxy proxy_host:8080 %s %d' % (target_host, target_port) )
client.connect(hostname=target_host,username='username', port=target_port, password='XXXXXXXX', sock=proxy)
```

But I need to create `SFTPClient`, not `SSHClient`. But I do not know how to pass the `ProxyCommand` to the `SFTPClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to SFTP server using a "custom socket", do:

```
proxy = paramiko.proxy.ProxyCommand(...)
transport = paramiko.Transport(proxy)
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```