# Python Paramiko, Attribute Error 'Nonetype' on close when trying to connect

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to connect through Paramiko to an external SFTP and passing an encrypted config file for the credentials. When attempting to connect with the following, I get an error for the exception client.close that states AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has not attribute 'close':

```
client = None
try:
    client = paramiko.Transport(hostname, port)
    client.connect(username=username, password=password)
except Exception as e:
    client.close()
    return 'Cannot connect to SFTP server: ' + str(e.args[-1]), []
# Go
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(client)
```

Comment: is hostname/port known ? it definitely fails to create the  `client`

Comment: see, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635131/paramikos-sshclient-with-sftp, it seems that host, port need to be passed as a tuple: `paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))`

Answer (score 0):

In the exception you're calling method `client.close()` which throws an error because the method `client.connect` did not succeeded, remove this method or create an exception for each possible error with to code handling that specific error.

Comment: This code works for another customer and I'm able to use the credentials through other means to login (winscp and mirth), but this fails from the get go. Is there a retry that can be attempted or another way to connect?

Comment: I will focus on the main question you asked: the exception code is wrong because it calls method `close` which must be called only when `connect` succeeded.