# Does Paramiko support certificate based authentication

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, public-key, openssh

Does Paramiko support certificate based authentication? The `key_filename` from the `connect` method mentioned that it supports both private keys and certs, is the certs here means Certificate-Based Authentication?

> key_filename (str) – the filename, or list of filenames, of 
>           optional private key(s) and/or certs to try for authentication

```
connect(hostname, port=22, username=None, password=None, pkey=None, 
    key_filename=None, timeout=None, allow_agent=True, 
    look_for_keys=True, compress=False, sock=None, gss_auth=False, 
    gss_kex=False, gss_deleg_creds=True, gss_host=None, 
    banner_timeout=None, auth_timeout=None, gss_trust_dns=True, 
    passphrase=None, disabled_algorithms=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramiko supports [proprietary OpenSSH public key algorithms supporting certificates](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.certkeys?annotate=HEAD).

The documentation of the [`SSHClient.connect` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) is more clear about it (than the documentation of the `key_filename` parameter itself):

> `key_filename` may contain **OpenSSH public certificate paths** as well as regular private-key paths;

Answer (score -1):

The answer above is solving the problem, where you have the certificate stored on the device and you have a path to the certificate file.

I was in the situation, where I got the certificate as a string, and storing the string into the file, than passing the path as the parameter was not an option.

I solved the problem like this:

```
private_key = paramiko.ECDSAKey.from_private_key(key_string, password=password)

sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()

sshclient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

private_key.load_certificate(certificate_string)

sshclient.connect(hostname=host, username=user, pkey=private_key)
```

Hope it will help to solve the problem, when the key and certificate are in the string.

Comment: Please do not suggest use of `AutoAddPolicy` without explaining the security consequences.