# Paramiko authentication with certificate and oprivate key

Tags: ssh, certificate, paramiko, private-key

I have a linux device which supports authentication with a certificate and a private key.

I have tried to connect with:

```
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_fil("path to privte key")
client.connect(server,port,user, key_filename ="path to certificate file", pkey=k)
```

I cannot connect in any way to the device.

Under  windows with OPEN SSH I can connect to the device with :

```
ssh root@192.168.0.2 -p 22 -o IdentityFile=C:\client_key\client_key -o CertificateFile=C:\client_key\OTCsigned_certificate
```

Comment: Welcome! You might be able to improve your post by adding code blocks using the backtick `. Markdownmode is supported here :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by :
Renaming the key and the certificate as id_rsa and id_rsa-cert.pub.

At argument key_filename i passed the certificate and alongside with it the paramiko loads also the private key.

It is finally working.

Br,

Comment: Welcome! You can answer you own quesiton see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: In my case I solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/74534189/2186777