# Ansible custom library for SFTP returns error

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, paramiko

I'm trying to create my **first** Ansible library to upload/download files from our SFTP server since the current modules do NOT support SFTP protocols. Here's the `library/sftp.py` file (I removed the documentation part for brevity). I based it from [Paramiko's SSHClient with SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635131/paramikos-sshclient-with-sftp), which runs as a standalone script.

```py
import contextlib
from enum import Enum
import ftplib
import hashlib
import os
import tempfile
import time
import paramiko
    
from ansible.module_utils._text import to_native
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible.module_utils.parsing.convert_bool import BOOLEANS
from ansible.utils.path import makedirs_safe

def main():
    """Main execution path."""

    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec={
            "host": {"type": "str", "required": True},
            "port": {"type": "int", "default": 21},
            "user": {"type": "str"},
            "password": {"type": "str", "no_log": True},
            "src": {"type": "path", "required": True},
            "dest": {"type": "path", "required": True},
            "direction": {
                "type": "str",
                "choices": ["push", "pull"],
                "default": "push",
            },
            "protocol": {
                "type": "str",
                "choices": ["sftp"]
                "default": "sftp",
            },
            "ftp_mode": {
                "type": "str",
                "choices": ["passive", "active"],
                "default": "passive",
            }
        },
        add_file_common_args=True,
    )

    host = module.params["host"]
    port = module.params["port"]
    user = module.params["user"]
    pswd = module.params["password"]
    src  = module.params["src"]
    dest = module.params["dest"]
    dirx = module.params["dirx"]

    paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")

    # Open a transport
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))

    # Auth    
    transport.connect(None,user,pswd)

    # Go!    
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    if dirx == 'download':
      sftp.get(src,dest)
    else:
      sftp.put(src,dest)

    # Close
    if sftp: sftp.close()
    if transport: transport.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's how I use it in an Ansible task

```
- name: Download artifact
  sftp:
    host: "{{ sftp_server }}"
    user: "{{ ftp_user }}"
    password: "{{ sftp_password }}"
    src: "{{ ftp_rel_path }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ fullname }}"
```

I get the following error.

```
TASK [downloader : Download artifact] *************************************************************************************************************
task path: /path/playbooks/roles/downloader/tasks/download_sftp.yml:15
fatal: [10.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unable to import sftp due to expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant \"==\"?"
}
```

What does the error mean, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Start by just trying to parse your file with Python (`python library/sftp.py`) and fix the syntax error that crops up.

Comment: @larsks, thanks! That was a great suggestion, and I was able to find the error. However, I abandoned this code and went a different direction.